# retrieving values from complex array

Tags: php, arrays

i have array given below

```
 Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
                    [user_id] => 2 
                    )
       [1] => Array (
                    [user_id] => 4 
                    )
       )
```

i need to select these user id to fetch data from database and display in html table
i tried this

```
foreach($prevUser as $key => $value){

        print_r($value);
    }
```

and receive this not the values

```
Array ( [user_id] => 2 ) Array ( [user_id] => 4 )
```

how to get user id

Comment: use `echo echo $value['user_id'];` instead of `print_r($value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the user like below and fire queries using two ways first is.

```
foreach($prevUser as $key => $value){
    $user_id = $value['user_id'];
    //write your query here like "select * from user where id = $user_id";
    print_r($value);
}
```

the second and proper way is

```
$userIds = [];
foreach($prevUser as $key => $value){
    $userIds[] = $value['user_id'];
}

// stores all user_id on single array and then fire query like below

//write your query here like "select * from user where id IN $userIds";
```

I prefer to used second way instead of first way. I hope this is help full for you

Comment: but how could i loop userids  now

Comment: You don't need to create the loop for userids. just fire query directly without using loop like "select * from user where id IN $userIds".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$user_ids = array_column($prevUser, 'user_id');`

$user_ids is an array of user_id like this [2, 4], then you can traverse it with foreach like this,

```
foreach($user_ids as $user_id)
{
  echo $user_id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$array = Array(
    0 => Array(
        user_id => 2
    ),
    1 => Array(
        user_id => 4
    )
);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $user_id = $value['user_id'];
    echo $user_id;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You answer should be more than just code, please edit and explain your answer

Comment: here firstly the correct way to declare the array and fetching the data using the foreach loop,